# Smartparens and web-mode conflict to add extra angular bracket

Tags: web-mode, smartparens

I am fairly new to customizing my emacs, so please be gentle.  I did try to find a solution for this, but all I found was a page on git where someone asked a similar question but (as far as I can tell) never received an answer.

I have both smartparens and web-mode installed and am trying to work in .html.erb files.

The issue I am having is that whenever I type `<%space` I end up with `<%  %>>` (notice the extra angular bracket).

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to deal with this, and how I would go about it?  I don't really want to disable either of the packages.

Comment: Would you mind posting your previous solution as well?  Perhaps in the same post..  I'll give both a try

Comment: In that i  was disabling `smartparens-mode`,  so i have  updated  the answer. You  can  check  that https://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/15192/revisions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn off auto pairing for web mode and enable pairing for `<` & `%` in smartparens.

```
(require 'smartparens)
(sp-pair "%" "%" :wrap "C-%")
(sp-pair "<" ">" :wrap "C->")

(require 'web-mode)
(setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing nil)
```

Now when you press `<%space` you will get `<%  %>` with both modes enabled.